# Zoom property in CSS works with Chrome but not with Mozilla

Tags: css

For a particular case, I have to zoom out on the whole body of a web page.

So I took the time to search the various possible solutions but I'm faced with a compatibility problem with the zoom CSS property that doesn't work on Mozilla. I quickly encountered the scale property but it doesn't offer the same desired result, i. e. the equivalent of a conventional zoom out (CTRL -).

Do you know an equivalent technique that works on the main browsers ?

Thank you in advance for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom
This will tell you what is compatable for each browsers. Not a solution but this is why it's not working in moz.

Just a little searching comes up with using this

```
.zoom {
zoom: 2;
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(2); /* Standard Property */
transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
```

}

That should do what you're after :)

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer but the result is not the same. If, for example, you zoom in at 0.7, the width remains 100%. With the scale property, the website content no longer takes 100% of the width.